# how can i add item to Combobox in wpf at runtime

Tags: wpf, xamarin, combobox

how can I bind data to Combobox at runtime? I use template field in Combobox and i try to update Combobox item source in code-behind. but not update xamarin my Combobox in form.  and in combobox template field, i want to delete combobox item with a button that event name cbxDeleteStudent_Click. but i can't find comboxitem in code behind.

Please help me.

MyCodes:

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="cbxStudents" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel Width="150">
                            <Label Content="{Binding StudentId}" x:Name="cbxStudentId"></Label>
                            <Label Content="{Binding StudentName}"></Label>
                            <Button Content="Sil" x:Name="cbxDeleteStudent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="35"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding StudentId}" Click="cbxDeleteStudent_Click"></Button>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Code Behind

```
private void btnAddNewStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (EmployeeDbContext db = new EmployeeDbContext())
        {
            Student newStudent = new Student()
            {
                StudentName = txtStudent.Text
            };
            db.Students.Add(newStudent);

            if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} öğrencisi başarı ile eklenmiştir.", txtStudent.Text), "Bilgi", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                txtStudent.Text = string.Empty;
                (cbxStudents.ItemsSource as List<Student>).Add(newStudent);

            }
        }
    }
```

for delete combobox item

```
private void cbxDeleteStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (EmployeeDbContext db = new EmployeeDbContext())
        {
            Student selectedStudent = db.Students.Find(int.Parse((sender as Button).CommandParameter.ToString()));
            db.Students.Remove(selectedStudent);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        ((sender as Button).Parent as DockPanel).Children.Clear();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: Please provide the definition for the `EmployeeDbContext` class, and the code to bind the `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the the `ItemSource` used to bind to the ComboBox, is a `List<Student>`.

Use [ObservableCollection(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List<T>`, ObservableCollection provides ***notification***  when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed and the ComboBox items are updated, while `List<T>` doesn't.

Then you just need to add/remove the item from the ObservableCollection, without having to touch the ComboxBox's Items property.

To Add

```
(cbxStudents.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Student>).Add(newStudent);
```

To Remove

```
ObservableCollection<Student> students = cbxStudents.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Student>;
int studentId = int.Parse((sender as Button).CommandParameter.ToString());
Student selectedStudent = students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentId == studentId);
students.Remove(selectedStudent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer.